# Transactions not expired after timeout expired

Tags: neo4j

We're using neo4j (3.1.5-enterprise) for one of our services. (Over HTTP)

We set `dbms.transaction.timeout=150s` in our neo4j config file .

We have a scenario which may take more time than 150 seconds, but what we would like is for the transaction to be expired after 150 seconds anyway.

For some reason its not happening and the transaction continue until it fully executed but its not being stopped after 150 seconds, any guess why?

In our application logs I can see the following exception (more stacktrace details below):

```
neo.db.NeoHttpDriver - Errors in response:
  [NeoResponseError{
     code='Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailed', 
     message='Transaction timeout. (Overtime: 23793 ms).', 
     stackTrace='org.neo4j.kernel.guard.GuardTimeoutException: Transaction timeout. (Overtime: 23793 ms).
     ...
```

Also, our service steps(in the specific scenario that may take long time) in general is open a transaction, lock some common entity and proceed. Since the transaction is not expired and released(and therefor the common entity continue to be locked) after 150 seconds, then other threads may also be locked for a long time.

Thanks!
Orel

---

Exception stacktrace:

```
15:00:59.627 [DefaultThreadPool-7] DEBUG c.e.e.m.neo.db.NeoHttpDriver - Errors in response: [NeoResponseError{code='Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailed', message='Transaction timeout. (Overtime: 23793 ms).', stackTrace='org.neo4j.kernel.guard.GuardTimeoutException: Transaction timeout. (Overtime: 23793 ms).
            at org.neo4j.kernel.guard.TimeoutGuard.check(TimeoutGuard.java:71)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.guard.TimeoutGuard.check(TimeoutGuard.java:57)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.guard.TimeoutGuard.check(TimeoutGuard.java:49)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.GuardingStatementOperations.nodeCursorById(GuardingStatementOperations.java:300)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.OperationsFacade.nodeHasProperty(OperationsFacade.java:343)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v3_1.TransactionBoundQueryContext$NodeOperations.hasProperty(TransactionBoundQueryContext.scala:319)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContextFor3_1$ExceptionTranslatingOperations$$anonfun$hasProperty$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContextFor3_1.scala:245)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContextFor3_1$ExceptionTranslatingOperations$$anonfun$hasProperty$1.apply(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContextFor3_1.scala:245)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContextFor3_1$ExceptionTranslatingOperations$$anonfun$hasProperty$1.apply(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContextFor3_1.scala:245)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v3_1.ExceptionTranslationSupport$class.translateException(ExceptionTranslationSupport.scala:32)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContextFor3_1.translateException(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContextFor3_1.scala:34)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContextFor3_1$ExceptionTranslatingOperations.hasProperty(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContextFor3_1.scala:245)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.spi.DelegatingOperations.hasProperty(DelegatingQueryContext.scala:221)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.pipes.AbstractSetPropertyOperation.setProperty(SetOperation.scala:98)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.pipes.SetEntityPropertyOperation.set(SetOperation.scala:117)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.pipes.SetPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(SetPipe.scala:31)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.pipes.SetPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(SetPipe.scala:30)
            at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
            at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
            at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$next$1.apply(ResultIterator.scala:71)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$next$1.apply(ResultIterator.scala:68)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$failIfThrows$1.apply(ResultIterator.scala:94)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.ClosingIterator.decoratedCypherException(ResultIterator.scala:103)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.ClosingIterator.failIfThrows(ResultIterator.scala:92)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.ClosingIterator.next(ResultIterator.scala:68)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.ClosingIterator.next(ResultIterator.scala:49)
            at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.ClosingIterator.foreach(ResultIterator.scala:49)
            at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:183)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:45)
            at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.ClosingIterator.to(ResultIterator.scala:49)
            at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toList(TraversableOnce.scala:294)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.ClosingIterator.toList(ResultIterator.scala:49)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.EagerResultIterator.<init>(ResultIterator.scala:35)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.ClosingIterator.toEager(ResultIterator.scala:53)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.executionplan.DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory$ExecutionWorkflowBuilder.buildResultIterator(DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory.scala:109)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.executionplan.DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory$ExecutionWorkflowBuilder.createResults(DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory.scala:99)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.executionplan.DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory$ExecutionWorkflowBuilder.build(DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory.scala:68)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.executionplan.InterpretedExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$getExecutionPlanFunction$1.apply(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:164)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.executionplan.InterpretedExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$getExecutionPlanFunction$1.apply(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:148)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_1.executionplan.InterpretedExecutionPlanBuilder$$anon$1.run(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:123)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.CompatibilityFor3_1$ExecutionPlanWrapper$$anonfun$run$1.apply(CompatibilityFor3_1.scala:275)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.CompatibilityFor3_1$ExecutionPlanWrapper$$anonfun$run$1.apply(CompatibilityFor3_1.scala:273)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.exceptionHandlerFor3_1$runSafely$.apply(CompatibilityFor3_1.scala:190)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.CompatibilityFor3_1$ExecutionPlanWrapper.run(CompatibilityFor3_1.scala:273)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.PreparedPlanExecution.execute(PreparedPlanExecution.scala:26)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:107)
            at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.executeQuery(ExecutionEngine.java:59)
            at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionHandle.safelyExecute(TransactionHandle.java:371)
            at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionHandle.executeStatements(TransactionHandle.java:323)
            at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionHandle.execute(TransactionHandle.java:230)
            at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionHandle.execute(TransactionHandle.java:119)
            at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.TransactionalService.lambda$executeStatements$0(TransactionalService.java:203)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is that the tx is waiting on a lock. Prior to Neo4j 3.2, `dbms.transaction.timeout` cannot cover the case of terminating a transaction that's waiting on a lock (or rather, it will mark it for termination, but the actual termination won't happen until the lock is acquired).

In Neo4j 3.2, `dbms.lock.acquisition.timeout` was introduced, which interrupts waiting on a lock and allows the thread to check if the tx has been terminated and take appropriate action.

Answer (score 0):

The following is based on an answer provided by Neo4j Support:

1. **`dbms.lock.acquisition.timeout`**
   As a starting point, `dbms.lock.acquisition.timeout` was only added in Neo4j 3.2, it does not exist for 3.1. where we don't yet have lock acquisition timeout, hence wait times on locks can over-runs past the set limit. Things like GC can also extend the time. However, as you're currently on 3.1.5, `dbms.lock.acquisition.timeout` would not yet be enforced.
2. **`dbms.transaction.timeout`**
   `dbms.transaction.timeout` marks a transaction for termination, but the actual logic of checking this and performing the termination happens on a running thread, not one waiting on locks, and doesn't cause the thread to wake up and check. Presumably the logic for terminating a thread upon timeout is that some other thread periodically checks execution time for a transaction, and if it has exceeded the transaction timeout, sets a `boolean` variable on the transaction to indicate that it is marked for termination. The actual termination of the thread likely happens in an event loop for the transaction, where it checks that variable to see if it's marked for termination, then terminates and rolls back. A thread that attempts to acquire a lock enters a waiting state when the lock is already held by another thread. During this waiting state, the event loop is not being processed, so the thread never reaches the point in the event loop where it can check if it's been marked as terminated and take care of it.

Bottom line:
`dbms.transaction.timeout` does not cause a hard timeout, it only marks the transaction as timed-out, which will cause it to rollback once the flag is checked.